# Using a class without creating a new instance of it

Tags: java, android

Newish to Java and very new to Android development.

I have followed the following tutorial - [Android tutorial (Basic Hello World App)](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html) and I am now changing it slightly as a proof of concept.

Basically I want to use a class I have created but I am having some difficulties.  The class is shown below.

```
public class Employee {

    private HashMap<String, String> employees = new HashMap<>();

    public void setEmployees(String name, String jobTitle) {
        employees.put(name, jobTitle);
        System.out.println(employees);
    }

    public String getEmployees(String name){
        return employees.get(name);
    }

}
```

I populate the `HashMap` from `MainActivity.java`. Using the set method above, this works as expected.  I have tested it and I can see the HashMap has the required number of entries.

My problem is when getting the data back.  How do I use the class.  I have a file name `DisplayMessageActivity.java` and the following code within it.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
        TextView employee_name = findViewById(R.id.employee_Name);
        employee_name.setText(message);
        TextView employee_title = findViewById(R.id.employee_Title);
        employee_title.setText(employee.getEmployees(message));
    }
}
```

The last line is where I am getting the error.  This is because it doesnt know what `employee` is.  I presume I need to add:

```
Employee employee = new Employee;
```

If I add this within the `onCreate` method it creates a new instance and therefore it has new values.  I have also added it just above `onCreate` with the same results.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you trying to set the properties of a class in MainActivity and get it in another acitvity?

Comment: @thelastchief yes I am

Comment: try: new Employee();

Comment: Switching from one activity to another will trigger the lifecycle and all your values will be lost!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retain the data you would want to make the variable and the methods static

```
public class Employee {

private static HashMap<String, String> employees = new HashMap<>();

public static void setEmployees(String name, String jobTitle) {
    employees.put(name, jobTitle);
    System.out.println(employees);
}

public static String getEmployees(String name){
    return employees.get(name);
}

}
```

This means that only one version can exist at a time. You would call the class directly and the method.

```
employee_title.setText(Employee.getEmployees(message))
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your Employee class code with below one

```
public class Employee {

private static HashMap<String, String> employees;

public Employee() {
    if (employees == null) {
        employees = new HashMap<>();
    }
}

public void setEmployees(String name, String jobTitle) {
    employees.put(name, jobTitle);
    System.out.println(employees);
}

public String getEmployees(String name) {
    return employees.get(name);
}
}
```

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Singleton in-memory cache` to keep your employees.

```
public class Employee {

    private static sInstance;

    private HashMap<String, String> employees = new HashMap<>();

    private Employee(){
        // No instance available
    }

    public static synchronized Employee getInstance(){
        if(sInstance == null){
            sInstance = new Employee();
        }    
        return sInstance;
    }

    public void setEmployees(String name, String jobTitle) {
        employees.put(name, jobTitle);
        System.out.println(employees);
    }

    public String getEmployees(String name){
        return employees.get(name);
    }
}
```

Later you can use your in-memory cache like the following:

```
Employee.getInstance().getEmployees(message);
```

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean "if lifecycle is triggered" but i think it'll work.